# Из строки в список словарей

Tags: python

Вопрос крайне извращенный.
Как из строки вроде: `'left1-right1,left2-right2,left3-right3,...'`
сделать список словарей:

```
[{
    'key1': 'left1',
    'key2': 'right1'
 },
 {
    'key1': 'left2',
    'key2': 'right2'
 },
 {
    'key1': 'left3',
    'key2':'right3'
 },
 ...]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Выглядит запутано, но... Сначала делим по запятой, потом по дефису и в итоге записывает в словарь сразу.

```
s = 'left1-right1,left2-right2,left3-right3'
print([dict([(f'key{ind + 1}', e) for ind , e in enumerate(i.split('-'))]) for i in s.split(',')])
```

Вывод:

```
[{'key1': 'left1', 'key2': 'right1'}, {'key1': 'left2', 'key2': 'right2'}, {'key1': 'left3', 'key2': 'right3'}]
```

Comment: Спасибо большое за ответ! Это выглядит очень близким к тому что нужно, но имена ключей (key1, key2) использовал для наглядности. В действительности там: type и value. Сори, что этим ввел в заблуждение

Comment: @VladislavKomissarov, ну там уже под себя смените.

Comment: ага, спасибо за помощь!